Check if click was triggered by touch in modern browsers
This question is an update to this one, but for modern browsers. (Unfortunately the answers here are outdated and/or not in vanilla JavaScript). Essentially I want to perform a simple test to detect if a click event was triggered by touch or mouse input.
The only answer in the aforementioned question that is foolproof and still works is to use the event.pointerType property. However, event.pointerType seems to only be defined in Chrome for the click event.
While I could use pointer-events (for instance pointerup), for which event.pointerType is defined for all browsers, pointerup behaves differently than click and is more similar to mouseup. In other words it does not register only true clicks, but also fires if the pointer was dragged around or started on another element.
For this reason, I would like to get this to work with regular click events. If anyone knows how I can reliably detect the input method it would be greatly appreciated.

Set up an event handler for the touchstart event on the document and set a Boolean variable to true in that handler. Then you can just look at that variable when needed.

A solution could be, first have a flag to check if get touched or not let's call it isTouched, this flag is false by default, and create an event listener on the touchstart event and once it get triggered it will turn isTouched  to be true,  also create another event listener for click and inside it conditionally check if isTouched is true, then reset the isTouched to be false, if it is with false, then there wasn't a touch event triggered, so it is just a click event.


let isTouched = false;
const testButton = document.getElementById('test');

testButton.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
  isTouched = true;
});


testButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (isTouched) {
    alert('Triggered by touch');
    isTouched = false;
  } else {
    alert('Triggered by mouse click');
  }
});
<button id="test">Test</button>




You have the right idea, but OP has said they want a vanilla JS solution (also question was not tagged w/JQuery).

@ScottMarcus Oh, I didn't notice that, I will update the code.

Thank you! This should work well enough!

A similar approach to the accepted answer but hiding the implementation by dispatching a PointerEvent for those browsers that do not support yet click event as PointerEvent
We can create a wrapper function that adds the click listener
and handles the logic for touch devices
function addPointerClickEvent(target, listener, options) {

  let isTouch = false

  const listenerWrapper = event => {
    if (!(event instanceof PointerEvent)) {
      const pointerType = isTouch ? 'touch' : 'mouse'

      const eventOptions = {...event, pointerType}

      const pointerEvent = new PointerEvent('click', eventOptions)

      target.dispatchEvent(pointerEvent)

      isTouch = false

      return
    }

    listener.call(target, event)
  }

  target.addEventListener(
    'touchstart',
    event => isTouch = true,
    {capture: true},
  )

  target.addEventListener('click', listenerWrapper, options)

}

And once we have the function we use it like this
const target = document.querySelector('.target')

addPointerClickEvent(target, event => {
  console.log(event.type, event.pointerType, event)
})

